# How to lookup two variables in SAS dataset and update value

Tags: sas, lookup

I have a dataset where i have two variable namely ID and Telephone no and i want to lookup telephone no and update the same variable wherever its missing for IDs for ex:

In the attached example ID A and B has missing value in telephone column and i want to pick the same where it is available and update where it is not.

`Date   Visitor_ID                     Telephone number
1-Mar-16    1000003634_4152228768

1-Mar-16    1000094865_1269576832

1-Mar-16    1000103735_1035466360

1-Mar-16    1000103735_1035466360   fda6a5563867eeebf19fb3
1-Mar-16    1000108145_3760680616

1-Mar-16    1000123010_2631619556

1-Mar-16    1000123010_2631619556   fda6a75c3765e0e8f797b4
1-Mar-16    1000126547_974397207

1-Mar-16    1000126592_2744218771

1-Mar-16    1000137177_3054387520

1-Mar-16    1000137208_498258799

1-Mar-16    1000137208_498258799    fda6a5563660e0ebf295b3
1-Mar-16    1000137460_2624495603

1-Mar-16    1000137460_2624495603   fda6a6583763eaeaf29eba
1-Mar-16    1000151867_3243977925

1-Mar-16    1000151867_3243977925   fda6a15a3f63eaedfb94b3
1-Mar-16    1000166048_3215927260

1-Mar-16    1000174960_357067493

1-Mar-16    1000178443_623552771

1-Mar-16    1000183569_2728954199

1-Mar-16    1000220805_3781532691

1-Mar-16    1000220805_3781532691   fda6aa5c3a64e0ebfb96b0`

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a snippet of an actual dataset. Also, is there a reason you want to keep duplicate observations of ID and telephone number?

Comment: Hi, I have added the same, yes i want to keep duplicate entries as it is a transactional data and would provide the number of times any activity happens for a  telephone number over a time period.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution - it involves hash tables and key joins - you may not have seen these before. Hash tables are simply a table held in memory that you can access easily. Key joins are perfect for what you are trying to do here, you can use them to lookup on an index and update fields in an existing dataset.

```
data telephone_nos;
 length id $1. telephone $2;
 id = "a"; telephone = ""; output;
 id = "b"; telephone = ""; output;
 id = "c"; telephone = ""; output;
 id = "b"; telephone = "13"; output;
 id = "a"; telephone = "12"; output;
 id = "e"; telephone = ""; output;
 id = "d"; telephone = ""; output;
 id = "c"; telephone = ""; output;
 id = "a"; telephone = ""; output;
run;


/* Create a telephone number lookup table that is deduped and indexed by id*/
data lookup_telephone_nos (drop = rc index = (id));
 /*create a hash table with a lookup id*/
 declare hash dedupe();
 dedupe.definekey('id');
 dedupe.definedone();
  do while (not e);
   /*Only read in data with telephone numbers*/
   set telephone_nos (keep = id telephone
                      where = (telephone ne "")) end = e;
   /*Check to see if you have already seen this telephone number*/
   rc=dedupe.check();
   /*If you haven't add it to the hash table and output it*/
   if rc ne 0 then do;
    rc=dedupe.add(); 
    output;              
   end;
  end;
  /*Remove the hash table*/
  dedupe.delete();
  stop;
 run;

/*If you don't have enough memory to use hash tables to dedupe - then create
  the above table without deduping (see below). This may take up more    
  physical disc space, but the key join will still work as it will pick up   
  the first instance that matches*/

/*
data lookup_telephone_nos (drop = rc index = (id));
 set telephone_nos (keep = id telephone
                    where = (telephone ne ""));
run;
*/

 /*Use a key join to fill in the missing telephone numbers*/
 data telephone_nos;
  set telephone_nos;
  /*Use a key join to fill in the missing telephone numbers*/
  set lookup_telephone_nos key = id / unique;

  /* _iorc_ will be 0 if a match is found, if no match is found and error will be written to the log, therefore
     If no matches are found (e.g. the b and c examples) then make sure that these do not cause errors*/
  if _iorc_ ne 0 then _ERROR_ = 0;
 run;
```

Comment: Hi Paul, great start but the example i have provided is just a sample the real data set has 1 million rows, would this still work for this size ??

Comment: Yes - though it depends. Depending on how much memory your system has you may find my de-dupe method uses too much memory - in which case there is actually no need to use the hash table.I have successfully run this type of command on huge datasets though. Regards the key join, you will find that this is extremely efficient on large datasets. Where possible I use this over other join types, simply because it runs so fast.

Comment: I have edited my original answer to give you an option of not using hash tables. I also assume that your base table is probably wider than 2 columns, if this is the case, you should restrict the lookup table to the the field you are matching on, and what you are wanting to update - I have therefore added a keep statement into the above example which achieves this, though is redundant in the above example as the base table only has those 2 columns.

Comment: Yes the table is wider than 2 columns and i just want to update the Telephone column

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple solution requiring two easy steps.

```
data temp;
   input Date $ Visitor_ID $ Telephone_number $30.;
   datalines;
1-Mar-16    1000003634_4152228768 .
1-Mar-16    1000094865_1269576832 .
1-Mar-16    1000103735_1035466360 .
1-Mar-16    1000103735_1035466360   fda6a5563867eeebf19fb3
1-Mar-16    1000108145_3760680616 .
1-Mar-16    1000123010_2631619556 .
1-Mar-16    1000123010_2631619556   fda6a75c3765e0e8f797b4
1-Mar-16    1000126547_974397207 .
1-Mar-16    1000126592_2744218771 .
1-Mar-16    1000137177_3054387520 .
1-Mar-16    1000137208_498258799 .
1-Mar-16    1000137208_498258799    fda6a5563660e0ebf295b3
1-Mar-16    1000137460_2624495603 .
1-Mar-16    1000137460_2624495603   fda6a6583763eaeaf29eba
1-Mar-16    1000151867_3243977925 .
1-Mar-16    1000151867_3243977925   fda6a15a3f63eaedfb94b3
1-Mar-16    1000166048_3215927260 .
1-Mar-16    1000174960_357067493 .
1-Mar-16    1000178443_623552771 .
1-Mar-16    1000183569_2728954199 .
1-Mar-16    1000220805_3781532691 .
1-Mar-16    1000220805_3781532691   fda6aa5c3a64e0ebfb96b0
    ;
run;
```

First create a list of unique visitor_id/telephone_number combinations for the observations that are not missing telephone_number:

```
proc sql;
    create table temp2 as select distinct
        visitor_id, telephone_number
        from temp (where = (not missing(telephone_number)));
quit;
```

Then join it with the original table in cases where the original telephone_number variable is missing:

```
proc sql;
    create table temp3 as select
        a.date, a.visitor_id,
        case when missing(a.telephone_number) then b.telephone_number else a.telephone_number end as telephone_number
        from temp as a
        left join temp2 as b
        on a.visitor_id = b.visitor_id;
quit;
```

The above piece had an issue, as some visitor_id had no CTN in the dataset the due to which the dataset swelled many time.

these seemed to worked :

```
proc sql;
create table temp3 as 
select a.date, a.visitor_id,b.telephone_number
    from temp a inner join temp2 as b 
    on a.visitor_id = b.visitor_id;
```

quit;

Comment: Whilst the above method removes blank phone numbers to create a lookup table, in the event that you have an IDs that have multiple different telephone numbers, the above method would result in more rows than you started with, due to the nature of left joins. The above method is also far less efficient than a key join.

Comment: Yeah, so if OP has that scenario, we'd have to tackle things slightly differently (and it would have been helpful had he included concerns like this in his question if he is dealing with them). But that doesn't seem to be the case. The benefit of this method is that it solves the question asked in a straightforward fashion, and he's not going to run into any efficiency problems running it on a dataset as small as 1m obs.